# El archivo .htaccess es case insensitive?

Tags: web

El archivo .htaccess es case insensitive ? Osea diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas ? Indiferentemente del proyecto. Si se trabaja con CodeIgniter PHP nativo o Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Puede probar con:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteMap insensitive tolower:
>
> RewriteRule ^[/]*(.*)$ /${insensitive:$1} [R,L]

Recuperado de [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/69675/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-mod-rewrite-redirect-to-the-same-url-mod-case)